# issue with custom adapter and django-allauth

Tags: python, django, adapter, django-allauth

I'm using `django-allauth` for my project and I'm trying to use a custom adapter to do some work on `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` before the user is redirected after login, relevant code:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django.conf import settings

class DispersionAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        """ Retorna la URL por defecto para redirecciónar,

        esta lo hace formateando la cadena con el nombre del usuario.
        """
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.format(
                username=request.user.username)
        else:
            return "/"
```

so, I did the changes on my settings.py as the documentation explains:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/{username}/all"
ADAPTER = "dispersion.apps.adapter.DispersionAccountAdapter"
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "dispersion.apps.adapter.DispersionAccountAdapter"
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
LOGIN_URL = "/main/login"
```

So, when I run the server and try to login, I am redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/{username}/all` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/jorge/all` (if that were my user name). I'm not sure what's wrong with my set up. I tried the following without any problem at all:

```
$ python2 manage.py shell

In [1]: from dispersion.apps.adapter import DispersionAccountAdapter

In [2]: adapter = DispersionAccountAdapter()
```

Any advice or fix is very appreciated! :D

Comment: What version of `allauth` are you using? Only the latest development version supports `get_login_redirect_url`.

Comment: Sir, I'm using your `0.8.3` version! Am I doing something wrong by using that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 0.8.3 which does not support `get_login_redirect_url` yet -- support for this feature was added after 0.8.3.

See: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/11ee262c9b9ec4923e8f3a34c71a05dad1dbccbb/ChangeLog#L1-L9

If you need this functionality I suggest you use the development version over at github.

Answer (score 2):

allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter does not provide a method called "get_login_redirect_url", so the method in your custom adapter never gets called.

This method is located in allauth.utils.py

Two possible solutions:

- Redirect twice: redirect to some view where you do the work on your url and then redirect again. imo this is the "easy to implement" solution but ppl might find it a bad one.

OR

- Create a custom login form derived from **allauth.account.forms.LoginForm** and overwrite the login method. This method returns *the final response object*.

For this solution you need to use a custom login view. In your custom login view call the allauth login view with your login-form class set in the "form_class"-parameter. see **allauth.account.views.login** for details.

code summary (the provided code is not tested and written in the small stackoverflow window so it will definetily not work copy'n'paste, its just a small "howto"-guide to clarify the goal)

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
(r'^accounts/login/', my_login_view),
(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
...
)
```

forms.py

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm as AllauthLoginForm
class MyCustomLoginForm(AllauthLoginForm)
    def login(self, request, redirect_url=None):
        # the original response
        response = super(MyCustomLoginForm, self).login(request, redirect_ur)
        if self.user.is_authenticated():
            r = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.format(
                username=self.user.username)
        else:
            r = "/"
        return HttpResponseRedirect(r)
```

views.py

```
from allauth.account.views import login as allauth_login
def my_login_view(request):
    return allauth_login(request, form_class=MyCustomLoginForm)
```

Comment: well i just installed it with easy_install django-allauth and it does not support it

Comment: That's my point -- latest release does not support it, latest development version over at github does.

Comment: so then why did you downvote my answer? its valid for all those developers who dont want to rely on a development version... and i strongly suggest developers not to use any development version of any library if their software has to be stable.

Comment: @Jakob That's cool man. Thanks for your answer but if the main developer @pennersr is right, I've better wait until he release a new version of `django-allauth` or in any case, using the development version on github (after all, my software isn't stable yet)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
```

You need to add the following line to the form.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are answering a post which is 8 years old and has an accepted solution -- a versioning issue. Can you please add some context on why your answer is adding some new information?